# VB6 - Dynamically adjust tab width based on Caption length

Tags: tabs, vb6, width, caption

I am new to VB6 development (I understand it is pretty outdated. But maintaining legacy code).

My question is - is it possible to dynamically adjust the width of a Tab based on it's Caption length (i.e. dynamically flexing the width of the tab)?

Example: My English text for a tab contains 10 characters, but French equivalent text contains like 15-20 characters. Would it be possible to accommodate text in the tab without having empty spaces on either sides of the text in both English and French?

Comment: What type of tab?

Comment: `ActiveTabs.SSTab`

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the ssTab control and select properties. Under the General tab, select ssStylePropertyPage from the Style: drop down and NOT ssStyleTabbedDialog.

This will automatically adjust the size of the caption of all tabs based on the length of their captions.

The TabMaxWidth property is ignored when this is selected.

Comment: Sidenote: When doing such tasks you won't always have the luxury of automatic adjustments. Some objects, like Form, UserControl and others have a TextWidth property. Give them your text und they return the width needed.